Nuxt 3 - Cannot access variables in from created() and/or data() in mounted()
I have the problem that a variable that I create in created() cannot be used in the fetchData function under methods. It is undefined there. I can't reference this and I don't know how to do that.
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      p: ''
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await useFetch('XXX/api',{mode: 'no-cors'}).data.value;
      //data from res...
      let p = '[ '
      //p transformation with data from res
      this.p = p;
      //the output is perfect
      console.log(this.p);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    //the output empty/undefined
    console.log(this.p);
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData () {
        //other stuff

        //I need the p variable here 
        //this.p is empty/undefined
        x = this.p
    }
  }
}
</script>

I think the solution is to pass the this or to use the =>. But unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

useFetch is a lifecycle in itself, I recommend using $fetch instead. Otherwise, you have undefined because your HTTP call is probably not done yet while the call is happening and the DOM is mounted. Not sure if it's supposed to be blocking here but it is a bit weird to have one call in created and the other one in mounted.
